# Enforcing redaction and/or redact updates in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, accumulo

In Accumulo, you can enforce what records are returned by the `Authorizations` and/or server side iterators.

What mechanisms are in place to enforce this type of security in MongoDb?  I know that there is the `$redact` command for aggregation pipelines, but that relies on the user to restrict their own queries.

Also, how could you enforce that someone doesn't do an update on a document they they don't have sufficient privileges to update?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB authorization is, as of 2.6, collection-level and controls what operations a user can perform, as opposed to what documents they can see. This means, for example, that if a user has authorization to perform `find` on a collection, they can see all the documents in the collection and there's no way to hide specific documents from them.

You can enforce update privileges on a collection by withholding the update privileges from the user, for example by giving them just the [`read`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#read) role.

There's also a conceptual overview of MongoDB's security model in the [security section](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/) of the manual.

Comment: So basically, the answer is "No, there is no way to control access to data (collection).  It's all or nothing, and at that point you're on your honor to $redact documents you shouldn't see"

Comment: There are absolutely ways to control access to a collection using the role- and privilege-based security model, as I described. If you have read privileges on a collection and are connecting to the database directly, then you will be able to see all parts of all documents in the collection. But, as depicted e.g. [in the `$redact` docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/), you can control access to parts of documents using middleware and $redact.

Comment: So like you said - you can't do it *in the DB* (like Accumulo).  You have to have a middleware solution that you have to force onto people.  Example - I have a collection of employee records. I want team leads to be able to see contact info about their subordinates, but I don't want want them to see salary information. HR needs to be able to see everything.  Both would have READ access, but the team leads would be able to see salary info unless I make them go through a proxy.  This doesn't really scale well for generic solutions.

Comment: Both of those groups would access the database through some other application, which could have the appropriate middleware alongside it. It's not a proxy. In terms of scaling, it's just another part of an application built on MongoDB, and scales in the same way. There's nothing especially bad about it.

Comment: Well, sure there is.  I now have to maintain this "some other application" and I need to know the business logic of every application that wants to access my data. If I'm not the one maintaining it, then I'm hoping that they'll do the right thing when fetching documents.  I need to ENFORCE that they are doing the right thing, not just hoping that someone who's maintaining the middleware is properly $redacting the data.  Plus, I have the overhead of the middleware and limiting the API of what the end user can call to whatever the middleware implements.

Comment: If you control simply the database and nothing else, yet are responsible for enforcing document-level restrictions and can't trust or reasonably work with those responsible for the applications where such things would currently be enforced with MongoDB, then the current security model in MongoDB does not seem appropriate for you.